# How to show the exact number of clustered markers on google map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-ios-utils

I am using below code for `marker clustering` (for generating cluster icon with buckets) using `Google map sdk`,

```
   id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc]initWithBuckets:@[@10,@50,@100,@500] backgroundImages:@[cluster1,cluster2,cluster3,cluster4]];
```

It is clustering markers properly but It is showing `10+` or `50+` numbers on map. For example, If number of markers are `35` then it is displaying `10+` on map, when number of markers exceeds 50 then it is displaying `50+` etc.(refer attached screenshot below). I want to display `exact number of markers` on cluster Image on map!! I mean if number of markers are `36` then i want `36` instead of `10+`. If any one can help!

Screenshot :

[image]

Reference : [marker-clustering!!](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can manage it by changing one method of `GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator` class.

In `GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator.m` replace below method,

```
 - (UIImage *)iconForSize:(NSUInteger)size {
    NSUInteger bucketIndex = [self bucketIndexForSize:size];
    NSString *text;

    // If size is smaller to first bucket size, use the size as is otherwise round it down to the
    // nearest bucket to limit the number of cluster icons we need to generate.
    if (size < _buckets[0].unsignedLongValue) {
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)size];
    } else {
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld+", _buckets[bucketIndex].unsignedLongValue];
  }
   if (_backgroundImages != nil) {
    UIImage *image = _backgroundImages[bucketIndex];
    return [self iconForText:text withBaseImage:image];
}
     return [self iconForText:text withBucketIndex:bucketIndex];
 }
```

with

```
 - (UIImage *)iconForSize:(NSUInteger)size {
    NSUInteger bucketIndex = [self bucketIndexForSize:size];
    NSString *text;

    // If size is smaller to first bucket size, use the size as is otherwise round it down to the
   // nearest bucket to limit the number of cluster icons we need to generate.
   if (size < _buckets[0].unsignedLongValue) {
     text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)size];
   }


  else{
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)size];
  }

  if (_backgroundImages != nil) {
    UIImage *image = _backgroundImages[bucketIndex];
    return [self iconForText:text withBaseImage:image];
  }
  return [self iconForText:text withBucketIndex:bucketIndex];
 }
```

What i have done is, I have just change else portion and set `text` as `exact number` instead of `string with +`!

Comment: Awesome solution! I would like to know does it harm performace also?

Comment: The map count is only increasing if I remove a marker from cluster the value is not decreasing, Can you explain why this is happening @Lion